# Trying to browse a simple .sqlite file created by swift app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite

I followed a simple tutorial about core data ( [core data tutorila](http://ww.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) ) and the app works. But i liked to browsed the core data by using
the firefox extension. See this: [browse core data with firefox](https://swiftnow.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/find-sqlite-file-by-iphone-simulator-for-ios-8-from-xcode-6-under-os-x/)

While following the tasks described in [browse core data](https://swiftnow.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/find-sqlite-file-by-iphone-simulator-for-ios-8-from-xcode-6-under-os-x/) i don't see the expect values in taks 6:

- Expand the folder Table on the navigator panel on the left.
- Click on the data table of interest
- Select the button Browse & Search near the
  top of the app
- Select one of the records in your data table

I don't see the records with the names i added???

Also if i just add records (= different names nike, asics, puma) and i run the app i don't see these records only the previous "in-app" added records
[image]

How do i browse the core data??

[EDIT] here's the sqlite i downloaded from the app
[sqlite file](http://www.filedropper.com/singleviewcoredata)

[EDIT 2] A closer look and i indeed see only SingleViewCoreData.sqlite-wal becoming bigger, but this is not a standard .sqlite is it?

Comment: Could you gave us the sample file? Could you see the data in your app?

Comment: Does your Firefox extension support the SQLite WAL (write-ahead-logging) format, which is used by Core Data by default?

Comment: @JasonNam where should i upload the .sqlite file?  And yes i see data in my app

Comment: @JasonNam i use filedropper.com and edited my question

Comment: @MartinR, i notice when i add some names to the app the SQLite WAL file is the only files which changes, but unfortunatly i can't open it nor with firefox extension or the SQLite browser. I thought i would be as simple as the browse core data link suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for a way to browse your core data on your iPhone, this helped me out:

> To view Coredata from a device :
>
> Plug in the device -
>
> Start Xcode
>
> On the top Xcode menu -
>
> Select Window -
>
> Select Devices -
>
> Select your device -
>
> Select the app -
>
> Select the settings icon (gear shaped symbol to the right of "+ -") -
>
> Select Download container -
>
> Save it to a folder -
>
> It will have an extension of ".xcappdata" -
>
> Open FireFox
>
> (If you dont already have it - get the FireFox SQLite Manager browser
>   plug in) Select the SQLite Manager icon on the top right (looks like a
>   barrel with stripes)
>
> Select the open folder icon
>
> change Format [SQLite DB files] to All Files
>
> Browse to and Select your database
>
> In addition to the tables and columns (sorry - Entities and Attributes
>   ) you created in Coredata - you will see a few extra columns created
>   by CoreData itself.
>
> Hope this helps somebody. It's a bit of a bear, but worth the trouble
>   to see your database "in the flesh"

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788899/271898).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend opening your sqlite file with SQLiteBrowser - download it here http://sqlitebrowser.org

You can view the data by selecting "Browse data" and selecting the entity whose records you want to see.

[image: Image showing the browse data option selected]

Comment: Did you select the correct entity name? If you created the entity user then the table name is created with a z added to it eg "zuser". Also, make sure that your data is being saved in core data.

Comment: How are you extracting the .sqlite file?

Comment: "Also, make sure that your data is being saved in core data." ....well i followed http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial and it looks like it's working with core data. I also notice SingleViewCoreData.sqlite-wal is becoming bigger (kb wise) and last edit time changes if i add some names

Comment: i open the .sqlite with both the firefox extension as the standalone sqlite browser program (as you suggested )

Comment: Where did you get the .sqlite file from? If you are using simulator, search for the file in Developer directory and use the recently modified .sqlite file.

Comment: from the simulator `file:///Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15752599-FDAD-4098-9EF3-23D63D3EDFB0/data/Containers/Data/Application/7B89B089-4110-49C4-A581-B17B9C7938AF/Documents/`

just as these steps said: https://swiftnow.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/find-sqlite-file-by-iphone-simulator-for-ios-8-from-xcode-6-under-os-x/

Comment: btw i use `let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        print(urls)` to print the path to the 3 files so i can easily copy *this drives me crazy

Comment: @alex - did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into the same issue while trying to view it on sqlite browser.

Comment: I was able to see the database content of the sandbox downloaded from xcode for my iphone. But somehow the simulator one is difficult to browse.

Comment: @EmbCoder, sorry at the moment I am not working on this project (within 2 months I will again) and I have to say I can't recall how I did it. When I am working on this project again I maybe can help you out, but that might be too late. Hope you found your answer?!